# How to use ORI file sysstem on Ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, backup

How to use the new [ORI file system](http://ori.scs.stanford.edu/) on Ubuntu? Are there any documentations?

Answer (score 1):

There is a manual [here](http://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=2522721&ftid=1403940&dwn=1) (This is the paper from the original [ori-page](http://ori.scs.stanford.edu/)).

*Quote from page 154:*

"The following commands create and mount an autosynchronized file system.

Listing 1: Configuration of a user’s initial repository.

```
ori newfs MyRepo
orifs MyRepo
```

In the example above, a repository named
MyRepo is created, and mounted onto a directory with the same
name. By default orisync is enabled, but can be disabled
with the --nosync flag. Next, in Listing 2, we replicate
and mount the file system on a different computer from
the first host over SSH.

Listing 2: Remote mounting a file system

```
ori replicate --shallow user@host:MyRepo
orifs MyRepo
```

In this example we use the --shallow flag to enable the background fetch optimization. Data is fetched from the source in the background and on-demand, and once
enough data is replicated the machine will be ready for
offline operation. We mount the MyRepo
replica onto a directory with the same name."

*I have no idea what they are talking about, but maybe it helps the pros here...*

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a ppa provided by the developers:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ezyang/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install ori
```